# Grouping and sorting data with R

Tags: r

Super new to R - like, started yesterday new. I'm trying to group and sort a data set and it seems as though samples like:

```
aggdata <- aggregate(mtcars, by = list(cyl, vs), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Only work with numeric data. I've also tried working off this example: [R Dataframe: aggregating strings within column, across rows, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266983/r-dataframe-aggregating-strings-within-column-across-rows-by-group) to build something new for my purpose but it's not giving me the output I need.

For the example, I have a data set that would look like:

```
Name       DateTime
Jan        2017-05-26T12:38:50.537
Tim        2017-05-23T11:52:40.423
Rob        2017-05-24T10:52:40.423
Jan        2017-05-25T10:38:50.537
Tim        2017-05-19T11:52:40.423
Rob        2017-05-19T11:52:40.423
Jan        2017-05-22T12:38:50.537
Tim        2017-05-23T11:52:40.423
Rob        2017-05-20T11:52:40.423
```

I would like to group the data by name then sort the groups by time so the end result would be:

```
Name          DateTime
Jan           2017-05-22T12:38:50.537
Jan           2017-05-25T10:38:50.537
Jan           2017-05-26T12:38:50.537
Rob           2017-05-19T11:52:40.423
Rob           2017-05-20T11:52:40.423
Rob           2017-05-24T10:52:40.423
Tim           2017-05-19T11:52:40.423
Tim           2017-05-23T11:50:40.423
Tim           2017-05-23T11:52:40.423
```

After grouping is successful, this sample for datetime seems promising [Ordering date/time in descending order in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389288/ordering-date-time-in-descending-order-in-r)

In any case, if someone in the know could point me in the direction of an example that groups by string or alphanumeric I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Or maybe something like `dat[order(dat$Name, dat$DateTime),]` if your example is representative.

Comment: You should parse your datetimes first, e.g. `df$DateTime = as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format = '%FT%T')`

Comment: This worked great lmo and @alistaire, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` library:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
require(dplyr)
```

Use `arrange(data, Name, DateTime)` to order by Name, and within name by DateTime.

Comment: Forgot about arrange vs arrange_. Fixed.

Comment: I'm using this in Azure ML Studio and it's not liking the install.packages, but the dat[order(dat$Name, dat$Datetime),] worked.  thank you for taking the time to answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: In Azure ML Studio you can use `install.packages(“src/pack/pac.zip”, lib = “.”, repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
library(pac, lib.loc=”.”, verbose=TRUE)` to install a package, after changing the directory the package is located.